# Prevent duplication of row in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How to prevent duplication of row in listview?

```
 ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText(EmpID.Text);
 if (!listView1.Items.Contains(item))
 {
 listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { EmpID.Text, Fname.Text, Lname.Text }));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText(EmpID.Text);
if(item == null){
  listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { EmpID.Text, Fname.Text, Lname.Text }));
}
```

Or you can also use `IndexOf()`, although the above code is better (I think so):

```
if(listView1.Items.IndexOf(item) == -1){
  listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { EmpID.Text, Fname.Text, Lname.Text }));
}
```

Or by a little `LINQ`:

```
if(!listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().Any(x=>x.Text.Equals(EmpID.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))){
  listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { EmpID.Text, Fname.Text, Lname.Text }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why !listView1.Items.Contains(item) doesn't work?

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski I think that's by implementation of `Contains`, it may check the `Argument passed in`, if it's `null`, throws the exception. In your case, the `item` will be `null` if the `EmpID.Text` is not found in the `listView1.Items`.